# Create an average mdx calculate member

Tags: mdx

I want to create an calculated Member of average values ​​that despise too far below or above the overall average.
illustrating
Sometimes some of my products(one of my dimension) are sold on a promotion for $ 0.01. And for the calculations of minimum, maximum and average price I want to disregard these values​​.
something like a standard deviation

I have sql enterprise, then no aggregation meausures can be a solution, just dont know how to use them to build a consolidated meausure

Comment: how can i help you to understand?

Comment: well let me see, today my average measure are calculated this way
[Measures].Value /[Measures].Quantity
but sometimes my value measures contains values 0,01(promotion value) and i want to remove this values from the result

Comment: let me try to clarify this one more time
Imagine i have the product A with 100 sells
98 Sells values are between $2,5 and $3,5
1 value are $0,01 and other $7,5. i need to calculate the average,minimun and maximum from my 98 set values

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that:

```
Avg( sets, IIF( [Measures].Value ..., [Measures].Value, NULL ) )
```

NULL values should be ignored from the AVG function.

Comment: but this give me the same result as [Measure].Value / [Measure].Quantity because they are sum aggregation fields

Comment: If you exclude several values based on your condition, this will not give the same result.